# Router as switch between wall and main router

Tags: networking, router, switch

Here is the situation:

I have an old SMC router that I want to configure as a switch (or bridge, I'm not sure what it would be...) to act as a device that is connected to the internet outlet in the wall and just forwards everything to the main router:

Internet-plug ---RJ11-cable--> Router-As-Switch ----RJ45cable--> Main-Wireless-Router

What kind of configurations would this router in between need? Is this relatively easy to set up or do I have to invest in an adapter that bridges RJ11 to RJ45 ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. By router-as-switch, do you mean you want to turn it into a modem? or is there a modem prior to this device? This is important. If you have an additional modem, you can simply just plug everything into the LAN ports and leave the WAN port unplugged and it works fine. If you need the modem part, then things become more complicated.

Comment: There is no modem. My question was if there is somewhere to make the device in between invisible so it is just acts as a kind of adapter between the internet outlet and the main router?

Comment: Your "Router-as-Switch" have a inbuild dsl modem. Rj11 are used for telephony, so this device is actually a router and not a switch. A switch is not able to connect different protocols, only different media types. (ex. fiber ethernet with copper ethernet). You have to clarify your needs.

Comment: if "internet plug" is rj11, that means it's DSL and not ethernet.  You need a DSL modem, not a "router as a switch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing "internet plug" means the RJ11 port in the wall, which is the phone line, and likely a dry line where your incoming DSL connection comes from. This is not Ethernet and requires a DSL modem to translate that incoming connection into anything a computer with an Ethernet card can make use of.

A modem can be bridged (means it requires a router if you want more than one device wired through it, or if you want wireless) or it can act as a router, some of them even have a wireless access point built in. If the modem is bridged, you simply run the Ethernet cable from the RJ45 on the modem to the WAN port on the router. If the modem is not bridged, then it is acting as a DHCP server and is acting as a router. It may have one or more ports in the back. If you want to plug your router into it, you will need to disable DHCP in the second router (multiple DHCP servers on a network is not a good thing). Once you've done that, it'll pretty much act as a switch so long as you don't plug anything into the WAN port. You can enable the wireless access point and anything that connects to it will receive an address from the DHCP server (your DSL modem/router).